# Interpretataion of the value take by the numpy random.seed()

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, random, seed

I am curious to know, how the seed method interprets the value we pass to it. I know the seed method of the numpy.random package is used to maintain the state of the random function so that it will generate the same output every time we execute the code, but does it specify something that random function will generate whatever the number will be is statistically standardized or the variance of total number will the number you have passed to seed method or anything ?

```py
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(101)
np.random.randn(4,4)

# will give the output
0.421177  0.587635  0.788256  0.482779
0.606076 -0.313919 -0.750010  0.569556
-0.901587  0.674378  0.504509 -0.555530
0.187578 -0.688103 -0.803551  0.816346
```

Overall, my question is: Is there any properties in this generated number related to the number we provided to seed method?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for `numpy.random.RandomState` the seed used is for the Mersenne Twister pseudo-random number generator implementation.

If I understand it correctly, the seed is the starting point in the Mersenne Twister series.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.RandomState.html#numpy.random.RandomState

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister